# How to rerun groovy script after completing it

Tags: groovy

I need advice. First of all, I'm really sorry if this thread already exists, I tried searching for one but wasn't successful Im trying to rerun the groovy script after it's completion, but I can't find any information on this topic. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by rerunning? Can you show your current code?

Comment: What i mean by this, is a go to terminal, go to the folder where is my script, then $ groovy launchScript.groovy [args]. The script does it's thing and it stops. My goal is to rerun it after it finishes.

Comment: Why not put the "rerun" logic in the script itself? You could have something like a loop in the script...

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by rerun logic. I dont need a loop there, i just need to rerun it

Comment: When you say "rerun", the first thing that comes to my mind is "why not just call it again?". Now if you want to rerun it systematically, you can call it multiple times in something like a shell script. If the "rerunning" logic is complex, then you can do that in the script itself (have something like `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){}` around your main code... Is any of these options having a problem?

Comment: Well calling the script itself is my goal, but i don't know how to call it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195291/discussion-between-artjomdz-and-ernest-k).

Comment: If you want to repeat the script, put a `while true` around in your groovy script.  if you don't have influence over the script and you want to repeat from outside, you can do the same in your shell `while true; do groovy x.groovy; sleep 1s; done` (adjust or remove the sleep for a break between repeated calls)